# Why the entity manager is not injected by spring despite using @PersistenceContext Annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**Description**

when i try to persist an object with the help of the entity manager it seems that the entity manager is null, not instantiated even though i used the annotation (@PersistenceContext)!

any recommendations?

**Entity Manager**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ImplEmployee implements EmployeeInterface{

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager manager;

    @Override
    public void  save(Employee employee) {
        manager.persist(employee);      
    }
    //other methods...
```

**Main**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JpaSpringApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(JpaSpringApplication.class, args);
    
    Employee e = new Employee();
    
    e.setId(4444);
    e.setName("Nathan");
    e.setSalary(543.87);
    
    ImplEmployee i = new ImplEmployee();
    i.save(e);
            
   }
 }
```

**output**

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke 
 "javax.persistence.EntityManager.persist(Object)" because "this.manager" is null
 at com.spring.jpa.demo.implemployee.ImplEmployee.save(ImplEmployee.java:25)
 at com.spring.jpa.demo.main.JpaSpringApplication.main(JpaSpringApplication.java:19)
```

Comment: Is `ImplEmployee` custom repository ?

Comment: @code_mechanic yep

Comment: I think, one user already answered the problem in your code, so it doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 1):

Because of this line: `ImplEmployee i = new ImplEmployee();` there is no `ImplEmployee` in the application context.

You should autowire `ImplEmployee`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JpaSpringApplication implements CommandLineRunner  {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpaSpringApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Autowired
    ImplEmployee implEmployee;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Employee e = new Employee();
    
        e.setId(4444);
        e.setName("Nathan");
        e.setSalary(543.87);
    
        implEmployee.save(e);
    }
}
```

Making an `@Autowired` field `static` is not a good idea. You can use the way above. A better approach is to create an `EmployeeService` class with `@Service` annotation. Then the same way you can autowire `ImplEmployee` and save the record in a method like `saveEmployee()`.

Comment: i tried it, and it asked me to change ImplEmployee to static,  and i did but it still not injecting the EntityManager !

Comment: @JhonathanMartini I'm adding an update...

Comment: unfortunately all of this couldn't work for me !